# How to turn a binary string into a byte?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, utf

If I take the letter 'à' and encode it in UTF-8 I obtain the following result:

```
'à'.encode('utf-8')
>> b'\xc3\xa0'
```

Now from a bytearray I would like to convert 'à' into a binary string and turn it back into 'à'. To do so I execute the following code:

```
byte = bytearray('à','utf-8')
for x in byte:
    print(bin(x))
```

I get `0b11000011`and`0b10100000`, which is 195 and 160. Then, I fuse them together and take the `0b` part out. Now I execute this code:

```
s = '1100001110100000'
value1 =  s[0:8].encode('utf-8')
value2 =  s[9:16].encode('utf-8')
value = value1 + value2
print(chr(int(value, 2)))
>> 憠
```

No matter how I develop the later part I get symbols and never seem to be able to get back my 'à'. I would like to know why is that? And how can I get an 'à'.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> bytes(int(s[i:i+8], 2) for i in range(0, len(s), 8)).decode('utf-8')
'à'
```

There are multiple parts to this. The `bytes` constructor creates a byte string from a sequence of integers. The integers are formed from strings using `int` with a base of 2. The `range` combined with the slicing peels off 8 characters at a time. Finally `decode` converts those bytes back into Unicode characters.

Comment: Note also that the OP can use `''.join('{:08b}'.format(i) for i in byte)` on the original byte-array object. This is pretty similar: we take the byte-array apart, one byte at a time, and format each one using `:08b` to get an eight-bit zero-filled string representation, then join all the strings without whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

you need your second bits to be `s[8:16]` (or just `s[8:]`) otherwise you get `0100000`

you also need to convert you "bit string" back to an integer before thinking of it as a byte with `int("0010101",2)`

```
s = '1100001110100000'
value1 =  bytearray([int(s[:8],2), # bits 0..7 (8 total)
                     int(s[8:],2)] # bits 8..15 (8 total)
) 
print(value1.decode("utf8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the base-2 value back to an integer with `int(s,2)`, convert that integer to a number of bytes (`int.to_bytes`) based on the original length divided by 8 and big-endian conversion to keep the bytes in the right order, then `.decode()` it (default in Python 3 is `utf8`):

```
>>> s = '1100001110100000'
>>> int(s,2)
50080
>>> int(s,2).to_bytes(len(s)//8,'big')
b'\xc3\xa0'
>>> int(s,2).to_bytes(len(s)//8,'big').decode()
'à'
```